# Do you know applications that use "in deep" factory_girl features?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I do not really understand very well how to use factory girl in my application.
I have a lot of polymorphic relations so it is very complicated to construct test objects with associations.

I would like to find rails applications on github that do a great usage of factory_girl.
This way I can better understand how I can apply it in my project.

I found this one that helps me to set up my project:
https://github.com/gsluthra/dakshina

So do you know project that use factory girl efficiently with associations, polymorphic assoc, etc. etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one of these?

- https://github.com/thoughtbot/hound/blob/master/spec/factories.rb (Or other thoughtbot projects--it's their library, after all)
- https://github.com/diaspora/diaspora/blob/develop/spec/factories.rb

Just trying to think of some larger projects. ([Discourse](https://github.com/discourse/discourse), for example, appears to be using its own fixture system.)

Spree also seems to have a bunch:

https://github.com/spree/spree/tree/master/core/lib/spree/testing_support/factories

Comment: wow, that's some very complex factories. Thanks I'll take a look at these.